# MediaController is not visible in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

"Couldn't open http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider"

But I see the video , but without the Media Controller

this is the code :

```
MediaController mediaController = null;
videoPlay.setVideoPath(video_url);
mediaController = new MediaController(context);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoPlay);
videoPlay.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoPlay.start();
```

**Only happens in a AlertDialog**, Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

add this manifest file if u dont find in the manifest file
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

or try using setVideoURI

```
    MediaController mediaController = null;
    Uri videouri = Uri.parse("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4");
    videoPlay.setVideoURI(videouri);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoPlay);
    videoPlay.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoPlay.start();
```

Comment: Sorry I forgotten say that is in AlertDialog. Is not a internet problem and "setVideoPath" or "setVideoURI" both works, thanks you anyway